# MapServer Raster WMTS From PostGIS Column

Tags: postgis, gdal, mapserver

I'm going to guess this isn't possible, since I haven't seen documentation supporting this in either MapServer, PostGIS, or GDAL.

I have a PostGIS table with two columns -- `timestamp` and `rast` -- `timestamp` is of type `timestamp without time zone` and `rast` is of type `raster`.  I'm trying to set up a WMTS layer in MapServer that uses `timestamp` as the `wms_timeitem` and the associated `rast` as the `DATA`.

I've tried a variety of approaches -- `CONNECTIONTYPE` and `CONNECTION` of course although the MapServer documentation says that isn't supported for raster layers.  I've also used a GDAL PG connection in `DATA` instead (e.g. `PG:host=...`) but I see no way to select a specific column let alone tie that to the time request.  I obviously get errors with either of those approaches and no raster is produced.

I have no control over the structure of these tables so if this isn't possible with MapServer I will have to try something else (maybe just serving raw output via GDAL) and I am open to FOSS4G suggestions in that regard.

Comment: Normally time support is done with a combination of vector layer (tileindex) and raster layer https://www.mapserver.org/ogc/wms_time.html but that may be hard to adapt to PostGIS raster. I think I would make a layer for MapServer with https://www.gdal.org/frmt_postgisraster.html and use varialble substitution https://mapserver.org/cgi/runsub.html for making the time based selection `where timestamp=%time_variable%`. WMS request would then contain `&time_variable=2019-02-27.

Comment: Thanks!  This might actually work -- I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: @user30184 I was able to find a working solution thanks to your help -- I've answered it below

Comment: Thank you for so detailed answer. Users running MapServer on Windows may need to use escaping in some other places. Consider to make a bug report https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues about including the full connection string into error messages but check first if such issue already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @user30184's comment I was able to create a solution.  Though not a WMTS, I was able to create a WMS layer that has a modifiable timestamp variable -- good enough!

Before worrying about the PostGISRaster connection, set up your mapfile to serve a WMS and create a new raster layer where you will add the connection string.

First, let's make sure we have a GDAL PostGISRaster connection string working via `gdalinfo.`

```
gdalinfo "PG:host=... port=5432 user='...' password='...' dbname='the_db' schema='the_schema' table='the_table' column='rast' mode=1"
```

Supposing everything is correct and the database accepts connections from this IP and port, `gdalinfo` should return information for all the rows of rasters in the table.  What happens when this connection is used in a mapfile?

```
MAP
 ...
 LAYER
  ...
  DATA "PG:host=... port=5432 user='...' password='...' dbname='the_db' schema='the_schema' table='the_table' column='rast' mode=1"
 END
END
```

Maybe you get lucky, maybe you don't.  MapServer might tell you that it is unable to connect, and even with the maximum debugging level set and `CPL_DEBUG` turned on, you might not be able to get any useful information about the issue.

***NOTE:** If you're looking at the error returned from MapServer, you might notice something spooky -- the entire connection string is returned, including the password.  Please don't include your password in the mapfile, use a PGPASS environment variable or file instead.*

If you are otherwise able to connect from that server, the solution is likely simple, though not obvious: try removing the single quotes from the connection string.

```
MAP
 ...
 LAYER
  ...
  DATA "PG:host=... port=5432 user=... password=... dbname=the_db schema=the_schema table=the_table column=rast mode=1"
 END
END
```

Hopefully MapServer is no longer producing errors, and instead is returning rasters from the table.

A few more steps are required to return a specific raster based on a user-supplied timestep variable in the GET parameters of the request.

Create a working WHERE clause in your connection string first, such as the following:

```
gdalinfo "PG:... where='timestamp=\'2019-03-06 00:00\''"
```

This might work in your `gdalinfo` tests, but MapServer will likely produce a connection error when it is used in the DATA connection string:

```
  DATA "PG:... where='timestamp=\'2019-03-06 00:00\''"
```

Finding the magic combination of escaped string literals is not worth the effort when there is a simpler, cleaner solution -- Postgres's dollar-quoted string constants.  Try this instead:

```
  DATA "PG:... where='timestamp=$$2019-03-06 00:00$$'"
```

Now MapServer should be returning a single raster, pertinent to that timestamp.  Next, use run-time substitution to set that query to the timestamp supplied in the GET request.

```
MAP
 ...
 LAYER
  ...
  VALIDATION
   "timestamp" "[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]"
  END
  DATA "PG:host=... port=5432 user=... password=... dbname=the_db schema=the_schema table=the_table column=rast mode=1 where='timestamp=$$%timestamp%$$'"
 END
END
```

Now you can append, for example, `&timestamp=2019-03-06 00:00` to your WMS URL and receive the raster for that specified timestamp.